# How to create an ElasticSearch Type and make it searchable inside the Index

Tags: curl, elasticsearch, types, document, datamodel

I'm an `iOS Swift` developer and I'm using `ElasticSearch` inside my app. I'm trying to wrap my head around how to declare a `type` in `ES` , what's the difference between a `type` and `document`, and which is most similar to an `object/data model`.

In `Swift` I would create an `object` or `data model` like this:

```
class Sneakers {
       var condition: String?
       var name: String?
}
```

This is saying I created an object named Sneakers with 2 properties: "condition" and "name" both of `Optional` (the question mark) of type `String`.

I know to create and set my ES to an `Index` I use the following:

```
curl -XPOST <bonsai_url>/myIndexName //I'm using Heroku & Bonsai for my ES cluster
```

I can then set a type like so

```
curl -XPOST <bonsai_url>/myIndexName/sneakerType
```

Where I'm lost at is how do I set the index to use my Sneakers data model as a reference to search on? Inside my app users can search for footwear based on the the Sneakers name (Nike, adidas, etc) and condition (old, new, used etc).

I know it's something along the lines of

```
curl -XPOST <bonsai_url>/myIndexName/sneakerType -d '
{
   "sneakers": {
      "properties": {
        "condition": {
          "type": string
        },
        "name": {
          "type": string
        }
      }
   }
}
'
```

My questions would be in ES:

1. what's the difference between a `type` and a `document`
2. would `fields` be the equivalent of `properties`?
3. after I create my `index` name and `type`, how do I make the `type` to
   refer to my `data model` and it's `properties` so that it can be searched
4. my last question would be what's `_mapping` for and should I use that in my curl command instead?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `ES` a `type` is the equivalent of a `class/data model/object`.

In `ES` the  `fields` are the  equivalent of a class/data model/object's `properties`.

A `document` is the result of what is actually getting searched inside the index. If inside the `index` there are 2 pairs of Sneaker `types` then the `index` would have 2 `documents` inside of it.

`Mappings` is 1- how you make your `type` searchable inside the `index` and 2- how you set the `index` so that the `type` and its `fields` would equate to an `object/data model` and its `properties`. This `type` and its `fields` are what you’re going to run your searches on.

I first created a `type` by creating a file named `sneakerfile.json`
and added this code inside of it

```
{
   "sneakers": { // this is a type
      "properties": {
        "condition": { // it has a field named ‘condition’
          "type": "string"
        },
        "name": {  // it has a field named ‘name’
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
   }
}
// sneakers is being treated like my Sneakers Swift class/dataModel from the original question
// the fields “condition” & “name” are of type String just like my Swift's Sneakers’ class' properties (since Optionals are a Swift thing that’s not included here)
```

Then inside terminal I created my `ES index` which is named `firebase` by running:

```
curl -XPOST <BONSAI_URL>/firebase
```

1- Now that I have an `index` named `firebase`, 2- an `ES type` named `sneakers`, 3- I now need to make the `type` searchable in the `index` by 4- populating the `_mappings` key with it:

```
curl -XPOST <BONSAI_URL>/firebase/_mappings/sneakers -d@sneakerfile.json
```

Now that I want to see what's inside my `mappings` key when I run:

```
curl -XGET <BONSAI_URL>/firebase/_mappings?pretty
```

I'll get

```
{
  "firebase" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "sneakers" : {
        "properties" : {
          "condition" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "name" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// Final Result -the index named firebase now can return documents of type ‘sneakers’. You can search for those documents by searching on the ‘condition’ and ‘name’ fields
```

As a side note the above answer `definitely 100% works` so you can use it. I haven’t been back to this answer in over 2 yrs but maybe try creating and setting another `type` to a `sneakersTestFile.json` like this. **TEST TEST TEST** to see what happens. I haven’t tried this below myself but I know it’s easier to read.

```
{
   "sneakersTest": {
        "condition": "string"
        "name": "string"
   }
}
```

Assuming you already created the `index` named `firebase` run:

```
curl -XPOST <BONSAI_URL>/firebase/_mappings/sneakersTest -d@sneakersTestFile.json
```

Then run:

```
curl -XGET <BONSAI_URL>/firebase/_mappings?pretty
```

Search it to see what happens